Blazor Anchor Link Navigation Routing Issue with Multiple Parameter and hash id
I was trying to create Anchor Link or Bookmark for some contents. My issue is on click bookmark href link it scroll and take me to content right but my problem is it throws Unhandled Error throws on Blazor Page. Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Rendering.WebAssemblyRenderer[100] Unhandled exception rendering component: Cannot parse the value '7900#headerC' as type 'System.Int32' for 'Wid'. System.InvalidOperationException: Cannot parse the value '7900#headerC' as type 'System.Int32' for 'Wid'. . This error happens as its takes my # id  appended to parameter as single one but which two seperate ones.
Image :

Reproduction Link : https://github.com/yazh21/Navigation-Routing-multipleparameterwithhashid.git
My Reference doesn't contain parameters passed but I have parameters in my page along with hash id.
Reference for Anchor link : https://www.meziantou.net/anchor-navigation-in-a-blazor-application.htm

Can you try again

I am lost where should I look at? BrokenFormDemo file uses query part, not anchor, and I doubt query parameters are set during initialization.

Please Check Demo , DemoMain and AnchorNavigation razor pages
